# Laravel 5.1 Route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm developing a webapp with Laravel 5.1 and I started doing the user authentication, I added this routes to the routes.php file:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

And it works if I enter the link into the url bar but if I put in a template this syntax:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('auth/register') }}">Registra't</a>
```

I get the error Route [auth/register] not defined. What I'm doing wrong? Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`URL::route()` expect a named route, here you should use `URL::to()` or you can create a named route with

```
Route::get('auth/register', [
  'as' => 'register', 
  'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
]);
```

Then use `URL::route('register')` to link to the route `auth/register`

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't defined a Named route and `URL::route` accepts route name as it's first parameter. You just defined a path `auth/register`.

To define Named Route you can do this:

```
Route::post('auth/register', [
   'as' => 'auth/register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put
`Auth::routes();`
in `routes/web.php`

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me when using [auth0 tutorial](http://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/)

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

work for me, putting "as" and call the route for example:

```
Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'auth/logout','uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
```

and for the HTML:
y para el HTML:

```
 <li><a href="{{route('auth/logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
```

this solution work for me in Laravel 5.1